# Which countries can easily provide visa for attending a conference?

Tags: visas, indian-citizens, conferences

I am pursuing PhD (Psychology) in India. I haven't traveled to any other country.

I want to attend conferences outside India also. I am interested in genuine academic conferences. I had applied for good conferences in past, but unfortunately could not make out due to lack of time to book visa appointment for US.

But I think Countries like US have strict visa rules. I can't waste time in doing so much paper work for getting a visa just to attend 2 to 3 days conference as I am at the advance stage of my PhD and it requires more and more time. Can anyone of you guide me with the name of some countries which can easily (as compared to US visa) provide me visa to attend conferences there.

Comment: Unfortunately question is likely to be closed as opinion based which is not the case. There are country visa statistics which objectively show visa approval and refusal rates to answer this question without opinion.

Comment: I think that, unless your country of citizenship has reciprocal visa-free agreements with other countries, you will inevitably have to go through bureaucracy and time-consuming procedures in order to get a visa. I don't think there is a quick and easy solution to this.

Comment: @user56513 If so then post an answer illustrating such data.

Comment: Uk: https://ukvisa.blog/2018/11/23/uk-visa-success-rate/ 91.58% for Indians versus USA 74% so one can objectively say it’s essier to get uk visa than USA visa for Indians https://travel.state.gov/content/dam/visas/Statistics/Non-Immigrant-Statistics/RefusalRates/FY18.pdf

Comment: @JoErNanO Too much work to do the research. I’ve posted a uk vs USA comparison for example. The question is not opinion based, it’s data based.

Comment: I think you are asking the wrong place. At next conference you will attend, ask other Indian attendees about where there are good conferences and easy to get visa. Ask also the older PhD students. Unfortunately the best conferences change country every year, so it is also difficult to get right country on the right PhD year. academia.stackexchange.com could possibly be a better place to ask (academic visa are sometime different compared travel/business visa)

Comment: Answerabe, but way too broad. Who's going to search all the visa-granting countries other than India?

Answer (score 2):

Your visa application is typically only the tip of the iceberg with regards to the amount of work expected of you before and after attending a conference.

Ask your faculty adviser for support in your decision making. Expect to be required to  start with **rational considerations** such as:

- **which conferences are actually relevant for your academic specialty and current research**
- **can you present your own research** or only attend
- how to **get funding**

Those are also typical questions that you will need to answer in many  visa applications. Once you have your shortlist/conference: often conferences will provide visa application information, provide invitation letters and might even sponsor you. Your adviser will probably also have experience with visa applications and your university may also have an international  desk that can support you with visa applications and other travel arrangements  (usually they are not restricted to only support foreign students attending your university).

With regards to visa [citizens of India require visa for most countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visa_requirements_for_Indian_citizens)

[image]